# Change the canvas's shape when using Lambert Conformal Projection

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

With the supporting of matplotlib basemap, I can draw my netCDF files in different kind of projection type.

We always see the figure is in rectangular showing like this:

[image]

But I also see some figures showing like:

[image]

For now, I have some weather simulation data and I want to represent it on the map with Lambert projection.

The temperature of on time slice shows like:

[image]

So, here is my question:

> **How to generate the figure which the borders of the canvas fit the lcc projection like the previous one using Basemap?**

Comment: I think the borders of the canvas will always be rectangular.  You can achieve a similar effect by removing the axes and grid and setting the plot background to white (or transparent), so that the rectangular shape of the plot area is not visualized.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! This is an method worth a shot!